# how can a servlet in one jvm communicate with servlet in another jvm

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, jvm

can this be solved simply by specifying the complete url of the servlet in the RequestDispatcher?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do???

Comment: I was going through some book yesterday..I got this doubt..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian is true, use HttpClient to do that.

But anyway it seems to be a poor design to call a servlet from another servlet no?
You'd better make at least a service that will handle the request to the other servlet.

Answer (score 3):

If the two servlets are deployed completely separately, then the simplest means of communication is via HTTP and specifying the URL (after all, that is the API they are presenting).

Using a library such as [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) will simplify this process and manage sessions/authentication etc. if/when required.